# Storyboard error , How to add new one? Could not find a storyboard named 'Main'

Tags: ios, storyboard, uikit, swift5, xcode11

I actually deleted my Main.Storyboard and Created new one named Login.storyboard than I went to generalsTab->Main Interface->I selected my storyboard

Now I built and ran my app but I got this error message Thread 1: Exception: "Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/yuvrajagarkar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/68C8B58C-E573-4F93-8BD7-74F67915A4BA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F7F8D344-11C2-4269-BAC8-3CD4EC13DDB7/PetApp.app> (loaded)"

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to change it in the `Application Scene Manifest` section of your `info.plist`:

[image]